# How to disable ECHO DIALOGS for Windows Script Host running a vbs file?

Tags: windows, wsh

Ran into a problem today. I have a Windows Server 2003 with a bunch of .bat files that essentially start .vbs scripts. Every time an ECH is used in the script I get that annoying dialog box that contains content of an echo and requires to click ENTER all the time. How can I just disable the dialogs and keep ECHOs in the command prompt window only?

[image]

Comment: Please be aware that tags stand alone.  That is, selecting `windows`, `script` and `host` does not mean you're talking about Windows Script Host.  Please select tags with care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect the output somewhere else, i.e.

```
scriptname.vbs > textfile.txt
```

Comment: That is a solution, but not in my case :/ I know this was done before, because I just switched to afresh install of Windows Server 2003. Before, my previous machine with the same OS didn't have this dialog boxes.

Comment: Oh, in that case someone changed the default script engine for you.  See this: http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/windows_scripting/windows_scripting_resources/Change_Default_Scripting_Host.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Force it to run under `cscript` instead of `wscript`

If you are running the script manually, just put `cscript` in front of it.

Otherwise, this might give you an approach:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_engine_force.php

Comment: Another approach is to just change your default script engine to cscript.
`cscript //h:cscript //s`
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245254